# Monitoring triggers in web.config not working for .net core web app

Tags: azure, .net-core, web-config

I'm trying to implement a setting (see below) in a web.config file in a .NET Core web app. Web app is hosted in Azure. 
The setting is placed in system.webServer section and should restart the worker process on slow responses according to article:
https://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/blog/auto-healing-windows-azure-web-sites/

```
<monitoring>
 <triggers>
  <slowRequests timeTaken="00:01:00" count="10" timeInterVal="00:02:00" />
 </triggers>
</monitoring>
```

But when publishing the config file with this setting the web app crashes with error messages:

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

- The worker process is unable to read the applicationhost.config or web.config file.
- The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Anyone successfully implemented this setting in a .net core app hosted in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

I found that one setting was missing. The complete monitoring tag should be:

```
  <monitoring>
    <triggers>
      <slowRequests timeTaken="00:01:00" count="10" timeInterval="00:02:00" />
    </triggers>
    <actions value="Recycle" />
  </monitoring>
```